# datatables for jsp

Tags: datatables, taglib

When I searched for Datatables Tag Lib, I came across with two alternatives:

http://tduchateau.github.com/DataTables-taglib/index.html
http://datatables4j.github.com/docs/main.changelog.html (Datatables4j announces they are moving to a project called Dandelion.)

Is there anyone who has experience of one of that tag libs?
Which one is more robust?

Thanks.

PS. I'm a newbie in Twitter Bootstrap and Spring MVC. While I am planning to write a custom tag for datatables jquery plugin, I came across with above solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTables-taglib was the first project, very basic and very buggy.
DataTables4j was much more featured but the project has recently moved to Dandelion.

You can browse the doc [here](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/) and an example of integration in the new [Spring Petclinic app](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic).

Disclaimer, as required by StackOverflow rules: I'm the author of the three projects above.